# Calculating a line integral around a closed curve.

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $u_0$ be a fixed vector, and let $b=u_0\times r$, where $r$ is the position vector $x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$. What is $\int_C b.\hat{T}ds$, where $C$ is a closed curve?

Assuming $u_0=\begin{pmatrix} u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}$, I am getting $b=(vz-wy)\hat{i}+(wx-uz)\hat{j}+(uy-vx)\hat{k}$

$\int_C b.\hat{T} ds= \int_c (vz-wy)dx + \int_C (wx-uz)dy+\int_C (uy-vx) dz=0$

Hence, the answer that I'm getting is $0$. But the book says that the answer is wrong. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: OK I realise that my answer is incorrect as $y$ and $z$ may chance as $x$ changes along the closed curve. My book says the answer is $B(u_0.n_p)$, where $n_p$ is a normal to the plane containing $C$, and $B$ is some constant. How do I arrive upon this answer?

Comment: What is $\hat{T}$? The tangent vector, or normalized tangent vector to $C$?

Comment: @PedroM.- Unit tangent vector to $C$

Comment: In your edit you say that $n_p$ is normal to the plane containing $C$. So are you assuming that $C$ is a plane curve?

Comment: @Crostul- Yes. Sorry forgot to add that

Comment: Have you learned the Stokes theorem yet? It seems like a more or less straightforward application.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stokes theorem:
$$
\int\limits_C b \cdot dr 
= \int\limits_A \mbox{rot } b \cdot dA 
= \int\limits_A (2u, 2v, 2w) \cdot dA
= 2 \int\limits_A u_0 \cdot dA
= 2 A (u_0 \cdot n_A)
$$
where $(\mbox{rot } u)_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j u_k$, and $C = \partial A$ ($A$ is a surface with border $C$).

Your line integral calculation was probably parameterized wrongly.

Comment: Sorry, what is rot b, and what is A? Is A the area encosed by the closed curve?

Comment: rot$\vec a=$curl$\vec a = \nabla\times\vec a$